# Make $n$ numbers equal using pairwise averages

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms

Given $n$ rational numbers. Every time you can delete $2$ numbers, and add 2 numbers which are equal to $\frac{a+b}{2}$ (assume the number you delete is $a$ and $b$). How to judge whether it is possible to make these $n$ numbers equal in finite steps? If possible, how to construct it?

Comment: if $n=2^k$, then we can easily construct an answer using divide-and-conquer. Let the average number of the $n$ numbers is $x$. A sufficient condition is if we can divide these $n$ numbers into several groups and for each group, its average number is equal to $x$ and its size is power of 2.

Comment: You can suppose the rationals are integers, in that case a necessary condition is that the denominator of the average is a power of $2$

Comment: A simple example to consider is $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: If the average is $x/2^k$ where $x$ is odd, I can prove that it is possible to reach a state where there are only two values, one of form $y/2^k$ for $y$ odd and one of form $z/2^k$ for $z$ even.

Comment: By a wrong step on can destroy the solvability. For instance $[2,4,6]$ is clearly solvable in one step. But if one averages 2-4 instead one gets $[3,3,6]$ which is not solvable.

Comment: @YCor Yes, and from this one can conclude that sets of 3 numbers are solvable iff they are in arithmetic progression. Sets of 4 numbers are always solvable (as noted by jh w. What about 5 numbers?

Comment: @jhw Clearly $n=5$ is solvable if one number equals the mean, but the converse is not true. For example 1,1,4,4,5 -> 3,1,4,4,3 and continue as before. So two numbers whose mean is the mean of all 5 is also ok. But that's not the end.  I believe 5,5,5,5,10 (mean 6) is solvable.

Comment: More generally any non-2-power number $n$ has such an "irreversibility" phenomenon: if $n$ is odd start from $[2,4,\dots,2n]$ which obviously solves to $[n+1,\dots,n+1]$, but also gives rise to $[n,\dots,n,2n]$ which is not solvable. In general $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd and one runs the same argument with concatenating $2^k$ copies of $[2,4,\dots,2m]$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay no, [5,5,5,5,10] is not solvable because solvability is invariant under affine change and [0,0,0,0,1] is not solvable.

Comment: @Ycor Sorry, I agree with you. I did one operation backwards!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

Without loss of generality, we can assume the numbers are integers. I'll show that one can always achieve an integer multiset with only two values.

For a multiset $Y=\{\!\{ y_1,\ldots,y_n\}\!\}$ define $V(Y) = \sum_{1\le i<j\le n} \,(y_i-y_j)^2$.

Start with an arbitrary multiset of integers $X$. If there are two different values $x_i,x_j$ with the same parity, replace them by their average. This reduces $V(X)$ by $\frac n2(x_1-x_2)^2$ and preserves integrality. Since the reduction is at least $\frac n2$, we can only do this a finite number of times before all odd integers are equal and all even integers are equal.

Whether this helps the problem actually asked, I don't know.

Comment: The numbers are rational, so you should start with multiplying them by a common denominator. Also, for $V$ we alternatively may take the sum of squares of all numbers.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  First part now incorporated. The sum of squares is fine but then one has to argue what the minimum is (trivial, yes, but one extra step).

Comment: I do not understand. The minimum of what?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I take it back. To show that only a finite number of steps is needed, one has to know that the sequence is bounded below, but that is obvious for both functions.  I just chose one that reaches zero rather than some multiple of the square of the mean when all the numbers are equal, on a whim if you like. Our functions have an affine relationship anyway so the proof is equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The trouble is ''a wrong step on can destroy the solvability'' by @YCor. I have tried to solve this problem in this approach, but it doesn't seem to go any further.